# CDN not returning Excel 1.3 js code but requirements.isSetSupported("ExcelApi", 1.3) returns true

Tags: office-js

I have seen this happen intermittently and I thought it was a local dev/debugging problem but today the CDN returned a version of Excel JS that seemed to not have the 1.3 code but did return that 1.3 was supported.

```
<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This was working a few hours ago.

Also, I captured the excel js from
    https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/excel-web-16.00.js

on 11/10/16 and then today and compared them and 11/10/16 contained, for example, range.getVisibleView() but today's did not.

Happening in both Excel Online and Client.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: As of today, Excel1.3 APIs are now generally available from the CDN location: https://appsforoffice.edog.officeapps.live.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js

Comment: @SudhiMurthy, what is this location? You provided me with an "edog" domain before. Is that an official domain/location CDN for a released Microsoft Office-js?

Comment: @JimBarrett, could you check again with the regular CDN location?  https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/Office.js

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky, working great now.  Thanks.

Comment: @JimBarrett - sorry I gave the wrong address Please use the regular CDN as Michael mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different issues here, and both are being addressed (and we're putting some internal processes in place to ensure that we have a smoother process going forward).  This should only be impacting Excel API 1.3, all the rest are fine.  But yes, we did end up with a delay between 1.3 being available and reported as supported on hosts, and having the JavaScript on the CDN.

The CDN is being updated very soon, at which point the issues should resolve itself.  And once we have 1.3 up, it will continue to be there.

I'll update the thread once we have the CDN deployed and live.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I was planning a new version release that uses 1.3 APIs so if you have an approximate time frame that would help. If it is not soon I will disable the 1.3 features entirely.